# Cloud Composer Airflow task fails but functions complete successfully

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to write my first Airflow job using Cloud Composer. My DAG has three tasks, the first completes successfully, but the second task fails seemingly with emitting any failure error message. I am using the `PythonOperator` in the second task. The function being called executes a long running query and polls until the query is complete. Once the query is complete, I get a message saying that the data has been output to the correct table, but then Airflow treats the task as failed and retries the task again.

My `default_args` for DAG look like this:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    'email': ['email@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'dagrun_timeout': timedelta(minutes=30)
}
```

EDIT:

Here is my Python callable and PythonOperator. the `run_query` callable produces output in the Stackdriver logs and indicates that the actual function completes, but the task fails.

```
def run_query(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    creds = ti.xcom_pull(key='key value 1', task_ids=t1_id)
    service = adh.get_service(creds)

    return adh.start_saved_query(service,
                                 kwargs['customer_id'],
                                 kwargs['query_name'],
                                 kwargs['start_date'],
                                 kwargs['end_date'],
                                 kwargs['project'],
                                 kwargs['dataset'],
                                 kwargs['table'],
                                 parameters=kwargs['parameters'])
run_adh_query = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task2",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_query,
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule='all_success',
    op_kwargs={
        'customer_id': 01234,
        'query_name': 'queryName',
        'start_date': start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        'end_date': end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        'project': adh_project,
        'dataset': adh_dataset,
        'table': adh_table,
        'parameters': {
        'CONV_START_DATE': {'value': conv_start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")},
        'CONV_END_DATE': {'value': end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")},
        'LOOKBACK_DAYS': {'value': str(lookback_days)}
        }
    }
)
```

I'd greatly appreciate any tips!

Comment: The message is come from log ? or email ? Maybe task fail between sent msg and end of the code. You shoud paste your PythonOperator code.

Comment: @howie I only see in the Airflow UI that the job has failed. Stackdriver logs only say "Starting attempt 2 or 2" when the retry due to failure starts. I have added my python callable and python operator code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in GCP Cloud Composer [composer-1.11.0-airflow-1.10.9].

For long running tasks, there is a high probability(especially when using KubernetesPodOperator) that the task can be marked as Zombie by Airflow Scheduler.

Solution :-

I increased the scheduler_zombie_task_threshold configuration parameter value in scheduler from 300 (default 5 minutes ) to 1800 (30 minutes). After this I was able to run the tasks for up to 45 minutes and without ending in failed state.

How to change the Parameter -

1. Go to GCP cloud console.
2. Navigate to Composer.
3. Open the composer.
4. Go to AIRFLOW CONFIGURATION OVERRIDES tab
5. Enter the value :
   scheduler   scheduler_zombie_task_threshold  1800

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error handling in your code.

When long running query and polls is fail , raise AirflowException, this will cause the task to move immediately to failure state.

```
from airflow import AirflowException
```

ValueError can be used for fail and retry

Comment: Thanks. I found an error i'm getting in the airflow-scheduler that says "ERROR - <TaskInstance: <task> running]> detected as zombie". Then a subsequent error saying that this task was marked for retry. I guess it's thinking this task is dead because it's a long running task. Anyway to further specify that the task is still alive and working?